Proof of continuous image of compact set is compact
Theorem: Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact and $f:K\to \mathbb{R}^m$ continuous. It holds that $f(K)$ is compact.

I know the proof is contained in Spivak's Calculus on manifolds, however, I attempted to prove it by myself first. Here is what I did by myself:
Let $O=\{ O_i\subset\mathbb{R}^m: i\in I\}$ be an open cover of $f(K)$.
By a previous theorem, since $f$ is continuous and $O_i\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ is open for all $i\in I$, then, for all $i\in I$ there exists an open set $V_i\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f^{-1}(O_i)=V_i\bigcap K.$

Now, I got stuck after this, so I decided to take a look at the proof in Spivak's book. According to Spivak, the collection of all $V_i$ is an open cover of $K$. The problem is that I don't see how this statement is true. I mean, $f^{-1}(O_i)=V_i\bigcap K$ is always a subset of $K$, but how can I claim that the totality of the $V_i$ covers $K$. In other words, how can I claim that every point $x\in K$ is contained in $V_i$ for some $i\in I$?

Compare withe the answer here.

If $x \in K$ then $f(x) \in f(K)$ so that $f(x) \in O_i$, or equivalently $x \in f^{-1}(O_i)$ for some $i$. Thus $K \subset \bigcup_i f^{-1}(O_i)$.

@UmbertoP. Thanks for the comment. If I understood correctly, if $x\in K$ then $x\in f^{-1}(O_i)=V_i\bigcap K$ for some $i$. This means that $x\in V_i$ and $x\in K.$ Meaning that $K\subset \bigcup_{i\in I} V_i$

Let $\left( O_i \right)_{i \in I}$ be an open cover of $f(K) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ i.e. $f(K) \subseteq \bigcup _ {i \in I} O_i$ then
$$ K \subseteq f^{-1} \left( \bigcup _ {i \in I} O_i \right)  = \bigcup _ {i \in I} f^{-1}(O_i)$$
which is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by continuity of $f$. Since $K$ is compact it exists $J \subseteq I$, $J$ finite such that
$$ K \subseteq \bigcup _ {i \in J} f^{-1}(O_i) \Longrightarrow f(K) \subseteq f \left( \bigcup _ {i \in J} f^{-1}(O_i)\right) = \bigcup _ {i \in J} f(f^{-1}(O_i)) \subseteq \bigcup _ {i \in J} O_i$$
This shows that $f(K)$ is compact in $\mathbb{R}^m$.
